# Meteor saving image data to server collection

Tags: meteor

I am trying to save a screenshot of the user browser to images collection ( without ) having to first save the screenshot image to the users machine (client side), but I couldn't find any resource / information on how I can do so in Meteor, so was wondering if anyone can please help / guide me on how I can save the image data saved in the form hidden field shown below to the server collection directly? Thanks

TestPage.js

```
$('#target').html2canvas({
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
});
```

TestPage.html

```
<div id="target">
      <!-- HTML Content here -->
</div>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Meteor-CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) package. Convert canvas element to data URI and pass it as first argument of insert method when [initiate the upload](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#initiate-the-upload).

```
$('#target').html2canvas({
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
        Screenshot.insert(dataURI, function (err, fileObj) {
            // Inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and kicked off the data upload using HTTP
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting the dataURL directly, first create an FS.File, where you can set the name for it. In this case, for the name I'm using an _id from another document that this newly created image corresponds to (this is of course using Meteor-CollectionFS as pointed out in the answer above by Firdaus):

```
let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
let assetId = options.assetId;

var newFile = new FS.File(dataURL);
newFile.name(assetId+'.png');

YourFSCollection.insert(newFile, function (err, fileObj) {
  if ( err ) {
    //handle error
    console.log( err.message ); 
  } else {  
    //get your new _id
    console.log( fileObj._id );         
  }
});
```